# Separating war application name from war file name

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, war

Currently if i deploy a war file on tomcat named say `myapp.war`, I can access its url by http://localhost/myapp/MyServlet.

However what I want is to deploy a war with a version number in the war file name and still have the same url.
For eg, I want to deploy `myapp-1.1.0.war` and still have the url be http://localhost/myapp/MyServlet

Of course I need to keep updating the war and the version number will keep changing, so I cant hardcode the war filename anywhere. 
Is there any setting in `web.xml` I can use to keep the same url for the app regardless of the war filename?

Comment: If you just want to add a version information to your file name, check my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33822607/1458639

Answer (score 14):

The solution is to stop using the automatic deployment feature of Tomcat, which takes the shortcut of setting the "context name" (the `/myapp` part of the URL) to the portion of the WAR filename before ".war".

Instead, extract the WAR contents to the filesystem yourself and setup an XML file at `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[contextname].xml` which points the desired context path (such as `/myapp`) to the location of the application on disk (such as `/opt/webapps/myapp-1.1.0/`).

The [Tomcat reference docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Introduction) provide a good explanation of how Tomcat deploys applications automatically, and how you can configure customized logic for the mapping of context path to application file location (there are a handful of alternate ways to set this up other than the one I suggest above).

Comment: does this mean i will also have to update the .xml file each time i deploy a new version of the war with the updated filename?

Comment: i am a little confused. in this case what should the content of the 'myapp.xml' file be to make it point to the location of the war?

Comment: something like `<Context docBase="/path/to/your/webapp/root" />`. Tomcat will use the name of the file, without the `.xml` extension, as the context path. Also in regards to my symlink suggestion I just noticed in the docs that it states `If a symbolic link is used for docBase then changes to the symbolic link will only be effective after a Tomcat restart or by undeploying and redeploying the context. A context reload is not sufficient.`

Answer (score 8):

You can use YOUR_WAR/META-INF/context.xml for this. Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/MyServlet"/>
```

Comment: @Matthew Gillard As far as I know the tomcat docs say not to put a Context element in Server.xml.  They have no problem with META-INF/context.xml.  The docs even tell you how context.xml works. From the docs: "Context elements may be explicitly defined:

    * In the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml file: the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps."

Comment: Am I misreading it then?  The "path" section says:
"The value of this field must not be set except when statically defining a Context in server.xml"

Comment: I think tomcat's behaviour (and documentation!) in this area is very confusing.  Not least of which: if you decide you want to change the context-root of your webapp you have to manually delete a file from $CATALINA_BASE/conf (4th of 5 bullet points in the Introduction section on that page)

Comment: @Matthew Gillard The only time I've hand trouble getting META-INF/context.xml to do the right thing is when I'm trying to set the root context.  In that case I've found I have to delete the pre-bundled root webapp. Other than it seems to work fine. But you're right there do seem to be some inconsistencies in the docs/behavior. Possibly worth submitting a ticket to them?

Answer (score 4):

When using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) you can control your deployment's path by doing the followings:

Tomcat's conf/tomcat-users.xml:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>

  <user username="root" password="root" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

~/.m2/settings.xml :

```
...
<server>
  <id>tomcat</id>
  <username>root</username>
  <password>root</password>
</server>
...
```

pom.xml :

```
...
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- neglect /html below Tomcat7: -->
          <url>http://server:8080/manager/html</url>
          <!-- Refer to the server settings in your ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
          <server>tomcat</server>
          <path>/myWebApp</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ....
    </plugins>
  </build>
...
```

Start your tomcat first
Then build and deploy your application..

```
mvn clean install tomcat:deploy
```

..it will be accessible under `http://server:8080/myWebApp`

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting in web.xml for this.  I do not believe that it is possible to set this inside the war file in a cross-container way - there is no mention of it in the spec anyway - so each container does it differently.  `jboss-web.xml`, `sun-web.xml`, `context.xml` etc.

Comment: As I am using wildfly 10 so I changed it in jboss-web.xml and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use "**##**" symbols for noting version of *.war files in the tomcat. 
For example: 
`myapp.war` -> URL: http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyServlet 
`myapp##1.1.0` -> URL: http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyServlet (still the same, because all symbols after "**##**" are ignoring by tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, and indeed, as  [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4249/matt-b) mentioned, the [Tomcat reference docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes) provide a good explanation of how Tomcat deploys applications automatically, and how you can configure customized logic for the mapping of context path to application file location.

In my case, I used this advice (in 'path' explanation):

> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute (/path)
>   must **not** be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or **both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false**. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

so in my case, I switched both `deployOnStartup` and `autoDeploy` to false, so my WAR (e.g. a.WAR) was not auto-exploded to 'a' directory under webapps, but instead into 'b' directory, due to these settings:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" 
            unpackWARs="true" deployIgnore="${ignore.context}">

   <Context docBase="a" path="/b" />

</Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found all the advice on this subject somewhat terse and confusing. The below method works for me using a default tomcatee installation.

Suppose I have a war file named mywar.war. This holds a servlet mapping to '/hello'. I want to access this servlet from a url like localhost:8080/myapp/hello

This method avoids any changes to server.xml which is not advised as this requires tomcat restarts.

This method will fail is you deploy to /webapps as it will try and deploy the same war twice. Therefore I start by creating a new directory to deploy into. I use /apps but the dir name is arbitrary.

I now copy mywar.war into apps. Tomcat ignores this action.
I now create a simple deployment file named myapp.xml. Note that the name of this file defines the URL context the war will be deployed under. I believe you can use ROOT.xml to deploy under . The contents are as follows:

As described this needs to be copied into /conf/Catalina/localhost This causes tomcat to expand and deploy the /apps/mywar.war and set the correct URL context. The servlet is now available on localhost://myapp/hello (or :8080//myapp/hello from a remote client).

Note that for a relative address the docBase URL identifies the location of the war from the webapps directory - hence the leading ..