# Map different url to same web application in Tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

I am not clear on the following:
If we have a web application named: `SomeWebApp` under Tomcat's `webapp` directory, the url to access it is:
`http://localhost:8080/SomeWebApp`
My question is, is it possible to configure Tomcat so that other URLs would point to that web application?
E.g.
`http://localhost:8080/ADifferentApp`  will also point to the `SomeWebApp`?

From the `web.xml` I think is not possible since it is about the url patterns when you are inside the `SomeWebApp` scope.

So what is the proper way to do it? If it is possible that is.

Comment: maybe you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875413/separating-war-application-name-from-war-file-name/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I found to work best is to install Apache2 on the server and proxy all requests. Tomcat is surprisingly difficult to configure in other ways than intended. In my experience, Tomcat doesn't provide this functionality declaratively.

Comment: So using a proxy is the only way to go?

Comment: Ok. +1 is from me.I will leave it open for a while and if there is no other contradicting info I will mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather recommend Nginx than Apache as proxy. I'm recently working on a project that incorporates tomcat and nginx works as proxy.
Once you've got nginx you can acctualy map as many url's to access the same web application as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,its possible to map different context path to single application edit conf/server.xml file

```
> **> <Context docBase="D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7\webapps\SomeWebApp"
> > path="/SomeWebApp" />
> >     <Context docBase="D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7\webapps\SomeWebApp" path="/ADifferentApp "/>**
```

Access application with 2 URL's