# Deploying war file to Tomcat with a different path

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

If I deploy a war file to Tomcat, called for example ***foo-bar-1.1.2.war***, how can I deploy it so that it is extracted to ***webapps/bar*** and its URL root is ***/bar/...***?

My intention here is to keep the war file in the webapps server with its version information so that I know which version is installed but have it overwrite a previous version of the app.

I could deploy the war file using [PSI Probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/).  This would allow me to specify a target context for the web app. However, it means that I would lose any version information in the war file name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separating war application name from war file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875413/separating-war-application-name-from-war-file-name)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Tomcat will always extract the contents of a war file, to a folder of the same name (when it's configured to deploy wars - as default etc.).

You can extract it to a folder name of your choice. So if you unzip the contents of `foo.war` to a folder called `bar/` manually, instead of just dropping the war into the web apps folder, it'll still load the web application.

However, this is totally unnecessary as you can specify the URL pattern of the application without messing with the folder / war file name at all by overriding the context root element for your application:

This is often set in the Tomcat `server.xml` - but that practice is fairly widely discouraged. Instead, I'd suggest you use `context.xml` in the META-INF folder of your web application / war file:

```
<Context path="/bar" .../>
```

When the application is deployed, the `context.xml` should be copied to `/conf/Catalina/localhost` but renamed to `foo.xml`

Note that conext roots must be unique and there are some additional considerations if you're using the `autoDeploy` or `deployOnStartup` operations (Source http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

---

Other options include:

- Clean the web apps folder each deployment and drop your new `foo-1.1.0` war in.
- Include the version number in a flat file. `foo/version1`
- Or simply include the version in a config / XML file.

You could also use Ant (or an equivalent tool) to automate your deployments (and perform any of the above).

Comment: I thought there might be a way to deploy a war file without manually extracting its contents so that you could keep its version information but deploy it over an existing context.

Comment: What's your app version got to do with the name of the war file / application folder?

Comment: I've edited the question in the hope that it will be clearer.

Comment: The problem is knowing which version of the app is currently installed and reducing the length of its name in a URL.  You're right that I didn't make the requirements clear enough in the first place.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the canonical answer because you mentioned including the version number in a flat file, which is the approach I'm taking.

Comment: AFAIK, servlet-mapping "/bar" will not map to <ip-address>/bar but to <ip-address>/<web-app-name>/bar (as far as auto deployment of tomcat is true). Point if I am wrong.

Comment: @TechSpellBound Sorry, you are correct. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 14):

There is an important point to emphasize about the `path` attribute of the context fragment definition. To cite the [documentation on the topic](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html):

> When autoDeploy or deployOnStartup operations are performed by a Host, the name and context path of the web application are derived from the name(s) of the file(s) that define(s) the web application.

`deployOnStartup` **is the default behavior of Tomcat hosts**.

To follow the documentation, this has a very important consequence:

> the context path **may not** be defined in a `META-INF/context.xml`

According to the ways of [defining a Tomcat context](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context), this lets only two solutions:

- `In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory`
- `Inside a Host element in the main conf/server.xml`, which is a discouraged solution in a production environment as it requires restarting the server

Another solution takes advantage of the [`unpackWARs` attribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation).

In my point of view, for these reasons, the general and easy way to implement a subtle path in a production environment is taking advantage of the [naming](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming) of war files (what could include versions management and be a solution to your problem). A single sharp (e.g. *test#path.war*) in the war file names implies a segment in the context path (e.g. */test/path*). A double sharp introduces the version number (e.g.  *test#path##112.war*). This works whether or not unpacking war files, hot deployment or not, is deployment agnostic (manager or file system) and manages multiples versions of a same archive.

But if there is the need to have a path distinct from the archive name, it seems the only solution is the descriptor in the `/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory or the `server.xml` file. For these, you need an access to the server filesystem.

The relevant solution is highly related to the way Tomcat is configured and managed in the everyday.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it right yet, but this seems like the right way.  It makes the 'version' column in the tomcat manager app make more sense.  I'm trying copy/move apps to webaps like 'cp /tmp/tds-5.0.0-alpha3.war thredds##500a3.war` to keep version numbers separate for THREDDS.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to include a version info in your war file name, you can name it like: `my-app##1.2.3.war`. It gets unpacked to the directory `my-app##1.2.3` but the context will be just `my-app` (i.e. http://host/my-app/).

Works at least with Tomcat 7.0.55

Comment: To deploy this by URL one should url-encode the sharps # to %23, eg.
`http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/myapp%23%23v1.2.2.24%20(myName)&war=file:/D:/RELEASE.Tomcat.wars/myapp%23%23v1.2.2.24%20(myName).war `, otherwise deploy will fail by a file-not-found exception.